# Find the Big-O of some functions

Tags: big-o

Hey I'm having some troubling find the what's Big-O this function have, can anyone help me please?, also can you explain how you solved it?, Thanks to everyone(:

```
public static Node<Polinom> SumPolinoms(Node<Polinom> polinom1, Node<Polinom> polinom2) // 2.B
    {
        Node<Polinom> temp1, temp2, result, first;
        temp1 = polinom1;
        temp2 = polinom2;
        first = result = new Node<Polinom>(new Polinom(0, 0));
        while (temp1 != null && temp2 != null)
        {
            if (temp1.GetValue().GetPower() == temp2.GetValue().GetPower())
            {
                result.SetNext(new Node<Polinom>(new Polinom(temp1.GetValue().GetFactor() + temp2.GetValue().GetFactor(), temp1.GetValue().GetPower())));
                temp1 = temp1.GetNext();
                temp2 = temp2.GetNext();
            }
            else if (temp1.GetValue().GetPower() < temp2.GetValue().GetPower())
            {
                result.SetNext(new Node<Polinom>(temp2.GetValue()));
                temp2 = temp2.GetNext();
            }
            else
            {
                result.SetNext(new Node<Polinom>(temp1.GetValue()));
                temp1 = temp1.GetNext();
            }
            result = result.GetNext();
        }
        while (temp1 != null)
        {
            result.SetNext(new Node<Polinom>(temp1.GetValue()));
            temp1 = temp1.GetNext();
            result = result.GetNext();
        }
        while (temp2 != null)
        {
            result.SetNext(new Node<Polinom>(temp2.GetValue()));
            temp2 = temp2.GetNext();
            result = result.GetNext();
        }
        return first.GetNext();
    }
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble" is not a problem description. What reasoning have you used so far, and what doubts do you have? Be more specific, please.

Comment: Also: What language is this? What data types are those? What do all those methods on them do? How can someone confidently answer when they don't know any of that info?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I may have misunderstood the code, but wouldn’t this be `O(2n)`, because it just runs through each item of `temp1` and `temp2`. `O(2n)` simplifies to `O(n)`. The code could also be greatly simplified.